# Azure Ad segregation between roles and groups

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, rbac

net core application and trying to implement authentication and authorization. I have set of users and these users belong to different regions. For example I have region APAC and I have some users in it. Then I have roles like global admin or regional admin. Now these users are type of regional admin global admin etc. Now I want to return role claim in my token.  To return role claim in my JWT token I should add app roles in manifest. So how should I return app roles now. If I select as group then all users belong to that group emits this role details. I am little bit confused here. I have grouped users according to regions. Inside each region users are of type regional admin, global admin etc and they have different permissions inside app. Segregation of these groups vs roles I am finding lot of challenge and no use full document also I found. Can some one help me to segregate these groups vs roles.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have users with different roles under the groups segregated by the regions. When you are trying to authorize by group all the users with different roles of the group emit the group role details.

Assuming regional admin you mentioned as a custom role for your application(as there is no such role in AAD) following is a suggestable approach.

A user can be assigned to multiple groups and Roles can be assigned to individual users/groups.

Create groups separately for regional admin, global admin users and assign roles to these groups accordingly.

If you are using the role claim in the token for role-based access control, authorize applications based on the role permissions granted by the administrator to groups. Please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) for the detailed documentation on how to create/manage roles for an application in Azure AD.